# How to find the position of the cell that the mouse is pointing to?

Tags: python

I'm writing a python game.
There is a certain map in it (a two-dimensional array storing cells) and I want to make it possible to place blocks on them.

I have:

1. A two-dimensional array of cells.
2. the size of one cell.
3. the position of the mouse on the screen.
4. camera position.
5. Camera zoom (for example, zoom = 1 is the normal size and 1.5 is a slightly enlarged camera).

I want to arrange the blocks in cells by changing the size of the camera.
I have already done a search for mouse coordinates on the map in cells, but it not work when I zoom the camera

Here's what I wrote:

```
cell_size = 64
zoom = 1
camera_pos = getcamerapos()
mouse_pos = getmousepos()

def GetMouseCellPos(self):
    MapPosX = int(-camera_pos[0])  # Map position on the screen
    MapPosY = int(-camera_pos[1])  # Map position on the screen
    MouseMapPosX = -int(MapPosX - mouse_pos[0])  # Mouse position on the map
    MouseMapPosY = -int(MapPosY - mouse_pos[1])  # Mouse position on the map

    MouseCellPosX = int(MouseMapPosX // cell_size)  # Mouse position on the map in blocks
    MouseCellPosY = int(MouseMapPosY // cell_size)  # Mouse position on the map in blocks
    return MouseCellPosX, MouseCellPosY
```

I need to somehow adapt this code to the camera zoom
To make everything work fine

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem:

```
def GetMouseCellMap(self, mousepos: (int, int), camerapos: (int, int), camerasize, zoom):
    MouseCellPosX = int(-(-camerapos[0] - (camerasize[0] / 2) - -((camerasize[0] / 2) - mousepos[0]) * zoom) // self.cellsize)
    MouseCellPosY = int(-(-camerapos[1] - (camerasize[1] / 2) - -((camerasize[1] / 2) - mousepos[1]) * zoom) // self.cellsize)
    return MouseCellPosX, MouseCellPosY
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).